# Program crashed. Could not find what's wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
    int isbn;
    string price;
public:
    void setDetails()
    {
        cout << "ISBN ?" ;
        cin >> isbn;
        cout << "Price ?";
        cin >> price;
    }

    void getDetails()
    {
        cout << "ISBN: " << isbn;
        cout << "Price: " << price;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a;
    vector<Book> books;
    cout << "How many books to insert ?";
    cin >> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            books[i].setDetails();
        }
    for(int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            books[j].getDetails();
        }


}
```

When I run the program, the moment right after I enter a value for isbn, the program crashes. I couldn't find what went wrong.
Is there something wrong with my main function ?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 3):

You did not push any elements in your vector. You need to push them using `push_back` or `resize`:

```
int a;
vector<Book> books;
cout << "How many books to insert ?";
cin >> a;
books.resize( a ); // added by jpo38
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    books[i].setDetails();
}
for(int j = 0; j < a; j++)
{
    books[j].getDetails();
}
```

Comment: Yeah...I was actually editing my post while you were writting your comment (+1) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your vector was empty. Try adding this line:

```
vector<Book> books;
cout << "How many books to insert ?";
cin >> a;
// Add this line:
books.resize(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it like this, i tried it works ,

```
 int a;
    cout << "How many books to insert ?";
    cin >> a;

    vector<Book> books(a);
```

ie get size first and construct the vector with that size , that way you wont encounter segmentation fault